# Tricky situation with simultaneous opportunities

Tags: salary, job-offer, negotiation, employer-relations

I am currently employed at company A and did apply myself for a position at company B and another position at company C. After two interviews at B, company B agreed with me and sent me a job offer. Company C invited me for a second interview in mid January where I personally strongly expsct to get to an agreement too and get an offer mid-end January (no guarantee though, of course). My goals are:

- to have both offers from company B and C in front of me
- if I have time and company A wants to keep me, to get a stay offer from company A
- to compare the offers from B and C (and A if there is one)
- decide for one of these offers and ask the other companies to maybe give me better conditions

The problem is: company B who already made me an offer wants me to act fast and resign from my current position before end of Decembre. Company C has my second interview scheduled for mid January with no way to do that earlier (I already asked).

What options do I have? What is the best strategy to achieve the goals I described above? Both positions B and C are equally interesting for me. Keeping my current position (A) is not my preferable solution except they make a far better offer than B and C (note that I dont even know conditions of C) which I honestly do not expect, especially since offer B is already very good and I expect offer C to be at least equally to B or even better.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I've faced these situations, it's gone wrong.   Something about the universe - I dunno.

My personal advice is don't let the situation get to your head.  Be grateful for every offer and take it seriously, and individually.

Comment: You mean take offer B, correct?

Comment: In this case, if you really like company B and see yourself there, then yes.

Comment: @Acroneos, evaluate Company B's offer in a vacuum. Is the position interesting? Is the company good? Are the salary/benefits right? Does it provide the work/life balance you want? etc. If it's the right job, trying to compare/contrast it with A and C is counter-productive. Especially if you need to potentially jeopardize B's offer to *maybe* get C's offer. However, if B's offer isn't good enough, it's not good enough and move on.